# Add two tuples in SML

Tags: sml, smlnj

Is there a function in SML that adds two tuples of equal lengthes like (3,1,2) and (4,3,1) and returns (7,4,3)?

Thank You

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is no such function.

There also is no way to write one yourself without hard-coding the length, i.e. you can write a function that takes two tuples of length 2 or a function that takes two tuples of length 3, but it's not possible to write one that takes two tuples of arbitrary (but equal) length. SML's type system simply does not allow you to abstract over a tuple's length like that.

For a specific length, you can, of course, easily define it yourself:

```
fun addPairs (x1, y1) (x2, y2) = (x1 + x2, y1 + y2)
```